# ui activity MainActivity has no zero argument constructor

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm a very intermediate programer (still learning) and I only know the basics of Kotlin and I don't know most of the concepts of Android Studio .. So please explain in the simplest way possible

i try to add adomb ads in my app butafter three weeks of trying, I get nothing but errors

> Blockquote

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sudanese.stickers.kotlinized.debug, PID: 6332
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sudanese.stickers.kotlinized.debug/com.costafot.stickers.ui.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.costafot.stickers.ui.activity.MainActivity> has no zero argument constructor
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
```

MainActivity

```
    package com.costafot.stickers.ui.activity

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.onNavDestinationSelected
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import com.sudanese.stickers.BuildConfig
import com.sudanese.stickers.R
import com.costafot.stickers.extensions.logDebug
import com.costafot.stickers.extensions.toast
import com.costafot.stickers.toaster.Message
import com.costafot.stickers.toaster.Resource
import com.costafot.stickers.toaster.ToastMessage
import com.costafot.stickers.ui.activity.viewmodel.MainViewModel
import com.costafot.stickers.ui.activity.viewmodel.MainViewModelFactory
import com.costafot.stickers.ui.base.BaseActivity
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import javax.inject.Inject
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds

class MainActivity(override var mAdView: Any, override val AddRequest: Any) : BaseActivity() {

    @Inject
    internal lateinit var factoryMainViewModel: MainViewModelFactory

    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, factoryMainViewModel).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    }
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MobileAds.initialize(this)

        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        adView.loadAd(adRequest)

        setupToolbar()

        mainViewModel.toastSingleLiveEvent.observe(this, Observer(this@MainActivity::toast))
        mainViewModel.launchIntentSingleLiveEvent.observe(this, Observer(this@MainActivity::handleLaunchIntentCommand))
    }

  
private fun handleLaunchIntentCommand(launchIntentCommand: LaunchIntentCommand) {
    when (launchIntentCommand) {
        is LaunchIntentCommand.Chooser -> {
            launchIntentToAddPackToChooser(launchIntentCommand.intent)
        }
        is LaunchIntentCommand.Specific -> {
            launchIntentToAddPackToSpecificPackage(launchIntentCommand.intent)
        }
    }
}

// Handle cases either of WhatsApp are set as default app to handle this intent. We still want users to see both options.
private fun launchIntentToAddPackToChooser(intent: Intent) {
    try {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.add_to_whatsapp)), REQUEST_CODE_ADD_PACK)
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        toast(ToastMessage.Error(resource = Resource(R.string.add_pack_fail_prompt_update_whatsapp)))
    }
}

private fun launchIntentToAddPackToSpecificPackage(intent: Intent) {
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ADD_PACK)
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        toast(ToastMessage.Info(resource = Resource(R.string.add_pack_fail_prompt_update_whatsapp)))
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mainViewModel.loadStickers()
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ADD_PACK) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (intent != null) {
                val bundle = intent.extras
                if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey(RESULT_STRING_EXTRA)) {
                    val validationError: String? = bundle.getString(RESULT_STRING_EXTRA)
                    validationError?.let {
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                            toast(ToastMessage.Error(message = Message(it)))
                        }
                        logDebug { "Validation failed. Error: $validationError" }
                    }
                } else {
                    toast(ToastMessage.Error(message = Message("Cancelled but no validation error given.")))
                }
            } else {
                toast(ToastMessage.Info(resource = Resource(R.string.add_pack_fail_prompt_update_whatsapp)))
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun setupToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

    setupDestinationListener(navController)
}

private fun setupDestinationListener(navController: NavController) {
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
        when (destination.id) {
            R.id.hostFragment -> logDebug { "hostFragment showing!" }
            R.id.anotherFragment -> logDebug { "anotherFragment showing!" }
        }
    }
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu)
    return true
}

companion object {
    const val REQUEST_CODE_ADD_PACK = 200
    const val RESULT_STRING_EXTRA = "validation_error"
}
```

}

Comment: Replace `class MainActivity(override var mAdView: Any, override val AddRequest: Any)` with `class MainActivity()`.

Comment: its make error ( Class 'MainActivity' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract val AddRequest: Any defined in com.costafot.stickers.ui.base.BaseActivity )

Comment: Then get rid of those things from `BaseActivity`, I suppose.

Comment: Or, have `MainActivity` still have a zero-argument constructor (`MainActivity()`) and pass values into the call to the `BaseActivity` constructor: `class MainActivity() : BaseActivity(something, somethingElse)`, where you would replace `something` and `somethingElse` with whatever values make sense for your scenario.

Comment: really i don't understand

Comment: Read about the syntax for Kotlin primary constructors. Android Activities must have an empty constructor, and since you never construct activities yourself, you shouldn’t define any constructors at all that take arguments. Override your properties inside the class, not in the constructor.